# How can I input absolute file path as rest api parameter

Tags: rest

I have a function search to retrieve files from file system such as

```
GET /test/services/search//tmp/abc.png
```

but when I set the parameter for search function as /tmp/abc.png, it returns 404 error message.

I tried to use

```
GET /test/services/search/"/tmp/abc.png"
```

and

```
GET /test/services/search/\/tmp\/abc.png
```

and

```
GET /test/services/search/{/tmp/abc.png}
```

but none of them works

How can I input /tmp/abc.png as the parameter for this search function?

Comment: How is this API call handled?

Comment: the API implementation is unknown

Comment: Then you need to try how to achieve your result by experimenting. Without knowing how the API works, it's impossible to provide a specific answer